# Java Convert String into datetime Object

Tags: java

How to convert this String

```
Sat May 07 04:31:14 MST 2016
```

into datetime object.

Comment: Here are a few pointers: SimpleDateFormat and Calendar APIs..The rest is up to you...

Comment: You didn't even search

Comment: I search and even tried but i didn't find any satisfy answer, can you guys please help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code will do:

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat(/** TODO: Enter your pattern here */);
String dateInString = "Sat May 07 04:31:14 MST 2016";

try {
  Date date = formatter.parse(dateInString);
  System.out.println(date);
  System.out.println(formatter.format(date));
}
catch (ParseException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

For a full reference of the modifiers that are allowed in the date pattern, have a look at [this web site](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

Comment: how to convert date object to datetime because simple date format returns date object but i need datetime object

Comment: What DateTime class are you using (full name with package)? If it is ``org.eclipse.swt.widgets.DateTime``, you can simply do: ``dateTimeObj.setDate(dateObj);``

Comment: I am using joda datetime

Comment: You can use the ``parse(String)`` method then: http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html#parse(java.lang.String)

Answer (score 1):

Try following code:

```
String date="Sat May 07 04:31:14 MST 2016";
Date dateTime=new SimpleDateFormat("E MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy").parse(date);
System.out.println(dateTime);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use two metods

> DateFormat

OR

> SimpleDateFormat

Example:

```
 String str_date="11-June-07";
 DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("E MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy");
 Date date = formatter.parse(str_date);
```

Source: [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4216745/java-string-to-date-conversion)

Other Examples"

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
String expectedPattern = "MM/dd/yyyy";
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat(expectedPattern);
try
{
  String userInput = "E MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy";
  Date date = formatter.parse(userInput);

  System.out.println(date);
}
catch (ParseException e)
{
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

}

Source: [alvinalexander](http://alvinalexander.com/java/simpledateformat-convert-string-to-date-formatted-parse)